# Auto reload React component/view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've got a dashboard where I want to display the latest API data every few mins. I'm thinking about using a setInterval() in a componentDidMount lifecycle call.

Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes! Do you anything else in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you would want to do in your `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.apiCall = setInterval(() => {    
     this.getDataFromApi();
   }, [mins in milliseconds]);
 }
```

`clearInterval` when the component unmounts.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.apiCall);
}
```

API call.

```
getDataFromApi() => {
/*make your api call here and set the state*/
}
```

Comment: Works perfect thanks. Is there a way to save have a toggle button that allows a timer to be set or not? E.g someone can toggle a button to determine whether they want refresh or not? At the moment i've got a button to trigger a setState() to change refresh state from true to false but doesn't seem to go back to refreshing once i've reselected the refresh button. Maybe I should have a condition in "shouldComponentUpdate"?

Comment: would need more details, but you dont need to refresh react updates live so not exactly sure whay you mean

Answer (score 0):

For such requirement for fresh data, I would research the possibility to use push traffic, instead of pull. The server can push the new info every time there is a change and it will be more effective way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about this however there it a lot of data changing in the back end and I want to limit the api calls from the front end. Hence going for a set timed refresh approach.